# Experience as a Facebook Software Engineering Intern

Tags: facebook

I have an interview with Facebook for a software development internship.  I was wondering if anyone has experience or insight into working for Facebook.

I have looked through the other questions about common interview questions but wonder if there is anything specific Facebook may ask an intern.

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty good chance they'll look at your facebook profile. If you don't have one, make one. If you do, remove any keg-stand photos.

Answer (score 1):

You might familiarize yourself with their app api and look into what they write their code.  Showing some initiative will tell them you are interested and not just looking for check on your resume.

Answer (score 1):

I've never interviewed with them but some questions that I would expect might include:

Have you ever developed any 3rd party Facebook apps?

What skills do you have with PHP/MySQL?

Are you a social person?